# Dapper Error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'"

Tags: dapper

I'm following a course on how to use Dapper however I've come across an error I'm unable to find a solution for.

The error being `"System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'"`

I've done some debugging and have noticed that when my initialize function reads from the appsettings.json file, nothing seems to be available within the "config" variable that is returned.

This also seems to be the case for when the function CreateRepository is called after, a null string is being sent to the repository.

Would appreciate if someone can see what seems to be wrong?

**Initialize** - object of 0 options returned to config

```
private static void Initialize()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    config = builder.Build(); 
}
```

**Contact Repository** - when setting a breakpoint in ContactRepository - the parameter passed is null

```
 private static ContactRepository CreateRepository()
        {
            return new ContactRepository(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
```

**App Settings**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=.\\SQLEXPRESS2014;database=ContactsDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to have been that the "AppSettings.json" file wasn't being added to the location where builder.SetBasePath was hence why it was returning null. A manual copy and paste of the file fixed the issue